# Nest.js Sequelize transaction commitment issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am facing quite interesting problem that I cannot solve. Here is the issue. I have my Nest.js project and I am using Sequelize in order to communicate with the database. At some point I decided that I would like to implement functionality that would handle trasnactions globally. So, here is how it work:

1. Controller receives request.
2. Transaction starts.
3. Function in the service proceeds the request.
4. Transactions is commited.
5. User gets the response.

Here is how I implemented this. I wrote this interceptor that is applied globally:

```
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { catchError, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Transaction } from 'sequelize';

@Injectable()
export class TransactionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly sequelizeInstance: Sequelize) {}

  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const httpContext = context.switchToHttp();
    const req = httpContext.getRequest();

    const transaction: Transaction = await this.sequelizeInstance.transaction();
    req.transaction = transaction;

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async () => {
        await transaction.commit();
      }),
      catchError(async (err: HttpException) => {
        await transaction.rollback();

        const errorMessage = err.message || 'internal-server-error';
        const errorStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

        throw new HttpException(errorMessage, errorStatus);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I wrote this decorator, in order to get access to this transaction:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const TransactionParam = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.transaction;
  }
);
```

So, this way, I can access the transaction from the controller and pass it to the service:

```
@Controller('company')
export class CompanyController {
  constructor(private readonly companyService: CompanyService) {}

  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  @Post('create-company')
  createCompany(
    @Body() payload: CreateCompanyDto,
    @TransactionParam() trx: Transaction
  ) {
    return this.companyService.createCompany({ payload, trx });
  }
}
```

This is where the problem starts. First of all, let me introduce the database I have from this `createCompany` function:

[image]

Then, when I trigger this function, I get the error back this this payload: `insert or update on table "company_users" violates foreign key constraint "company_users_user_id_fkey"`.

Generally speaking, if you take a look at the `createCompany` function you will see that the sequence looks next:

1. Create User
2. Create Company
3. Create Comapny User

The thing is that everything crashes after step 2. Basically, the user is created, the company (which needs `user_id`) is created, but the company user (which needs both `company_id` and `user_id`) causes the error.

I checked database logs and here is what I found:

```
api        | Executing (9277a385-4170-4f91-9664-3ee9d3501fb3): INSERT INTO "users_settings" ("id","email_changed","user_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","phone","phone_code","code_sent_at","two_fa_token","email_changed","password_changed","recovery_keys_fingerprint","user_id","created_at","updated_at";
api        | Executing (9277a385-4170-4f91-9664-3ee9d3501fb3): INSERT INTO "companies" ("id","company_name","company_location","company_website","company_owner_id","is_confirmed","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8) RETURNING "id","company_name","company_location","company_website","company_owner_id","is_confirmed","created_at","updated_at";
api        | Executing (default): INSERT INTO "company_users" ("id","user_id","company_id","invitation_confirmed","invitation_sent_at","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING "id","user_id","company_id","invitation_confirmed","invitation_sent_at","created_at","updated_at";
db         | 2023-08-21 11:39:50.434 UTC [99] ERROR:  insert or update on table "company_users" violates foreign key constraint "company_users_user_id_fkey"
db         | 2023-08-21 11:39:50.434 UTC [99] DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(ad713365-a690-49c1-891c-158f39514ecd) is not present in table "users".
```

As you can see, everything happens as I was describing. Created record in the `users_settings` basically means that the user was sucessfully created, then, using `user_id`, company is created, but when it comes to creating the Company User, here is where it crashes. Below I am going to present the piece of `createCompany` function where it happens:

```
if (ownerExistingAccount) {
  to = ownerExistingAccount.email;
  userId = ownerExistingAccount.id;
} else {
  const createdOwnerAccount = await this.usersService.createUser({
    payload: { email: companyOwnerEmail },
    role: Roles.PRIMARY_ADMIN,
    trx
  });
  to = companyOwnerEmail;
  userId = createdOwnerAccount.id;
}

const companyCreationPayload = {
  companyName,
  companyLocation,
  companyWebsite,
  companyOwnerId: userId,
  trx
};

const { id: companyId } = await this.createCompanyAccount({
  ...companyCreationPayload
});

// After this line, everything crashes

await this.companyUsersService.createCompanyUser({
  userId,
  companyId
});
```

To be honest, I am not quite sure why it happens, but my guess is that it is because wrong database foreign keys. I think so because, as you can see from ERD, **in order to create comapny, I need to have a user. When user is created, the company is created successfully also, but it doesn't work for comapny user.**

I had a guess that it could be something with transactions, as you can see from the log error message, **it says that such user doesn't exist in the database, which is wrong, because otherwise, company wouldn't be created.**

So, what is the issue and how can I fix it?

Thanks everyone in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me, I feel myself the dumbest person on this plannet...

The problem was that I wasn't passing the transaction to this function:

```
await this.companyUsersService.createCompanyUser({
  userId,
  companyId
});
```

It looked like this:

```
async createCompanyUser({
  companyId,
  userId,
}: CreateCompanyUserInterface) {
  return await this.companyUserRepository.create(
    {
      userId,
      companyId,
      invitationSentAt: new Date()
    }
  );
}
```

And the fixed version looks like this:

```
async createCompanyUser({
  companyId,
  userId,
  trx: transaction
}: CreateCompanyUserInterface) {
  return await this.companyUserRepository.create(
    {
      userId,
      companyId,
      invitationSentAt: new Date()
    },
    { transaction }
  );
}
```

Today's lesson - pay attention to details.